# Truncate action bar items after the fourth

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Precondition**

I want to make an Action Bar in CSS. The **fifth item** which within the Action Bar should be half truncated when more than 4 actions occurred.

---

**Expected Result**

2 Actions

[image]

3 Actions

[image]

4 Actions

[image]

More than 4 Actions

[image]

---

See the code snippet below:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e9e9f2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inner-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 36rem;
  height: 7rem;
  background-color: #f08bc3;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 7rem;
  color: white;
}

.menu-icon {
  width: 3.2rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-title {
  height: 1.7rem;
  width: 7rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="inner-flex">
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-trello fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-tumblr fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-vimeo fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 4</span>
    </div>
    <!-- More than 4 Actions -->
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-skype fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean like this: https://jsfiddle.net/oxgqz6mf/

Comment: it's best when you do it with JS

Comment: Penny Liu, when you say truncate, you mean remove?

Comment: @fmsthird Cut Font-awesome symbol and title in half.

Comment: @PennyLiu like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WWmPGZ

Comment: @fmsthird Thanks, but I want to display the action items with space before, between, and after the lines. That's why I use `space-around` in the inner-flex instead of `flex-start`.

Comment: updated it. kindly check

Comment: @fmsthird Thanks, well done! This is actually way better. I add this syntax additionally to prevent the gap display. `x[index].style.marginRight = '-10px';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192547/discussion-between-fmsthird-and-penny-liu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a maximum of 4 items in your menu you can do this:

- set `min-width: 22%` on `sub-menu` (to fill 4 items in a container it is 25%, but you want to partially show the 5<sup>th</sup> one; and hence a little bit less that that),
- set `flex-grow: 1` on the `sub-menu` so that when items are less they fill the available space,
- set `justify-content: flex-start` on the `inner-flex` container so that the overflow is to the right.

Finish it up by adding `overflow: hidden` on the `inner-flex` container - see demo below:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e9e9f2;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 36rem;
  height: 7rem;
  background-color: #f08bc3;
  overflow: hidden; /* added */
  justify-content: flex-start; /* added */
}
.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 7rem;
  color: white;
  flex-grow: 1; /* added */
  min-width: 22%; /* added */
}
.menu-icon {
  width: 3.2rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-title {
  height: 1.7rem;
  width: 7rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="inner-flex">
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-trello fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="inner-flex">
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-trello fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-tumblr fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="inner-flex">
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-trello fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-tumblr fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-vimeo fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="inner-flex">
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-trello fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-tumblr fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-vimeo fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 4</span>
    </div>
    <!-- More than 4 Actions -->
    <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-skype fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much, you're amazing! :)

Comment: Hi @kukkuz, I just notice that there are two `justify-content` properties on the `inner-flex` selector in the same time. Should remain `flex-start` only?

Comment: @PennyLiu yes `flex-start` only :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this satisfies what you are looking for, make the following change to your CSS

```
.inner-flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 32rem;
    height: 7rem;
    background-color: #f08bc3;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it clearly enough. I need to `space-around` Items when the action items number less than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are widths specified in some elements the icons gets cutoff beyond it (`menu-title`,`menu-icon`). Are you looking for something like this?

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7rem;
  background-color: #f08bc3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="sub-menu">
      <div class="menu-icon"><i class="fa fa-trello fa-3x"></i></div>
      <span class="menu-title">Action 1</span>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="sub-menu"> repeated... -->
</div>
```

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ev497c0m/1/)